# Flush a Queue at scheduled rate and also on some property

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, queue, flush

I have a queue and want to flush it at scheduled time and also when it's full.
For flushing it at scheduled time I have created a timer task in java which can also be done using a executor service.
How do I flush it when it's full?
What would be the best way to do this so that the scheduled task to flush as well as the task to flush when the queue is full work in a concurrent environment?